# print dollar sign in python

Tags: python, mysql, enums, dollar-sign

I am generating mysql table schemas using information from another mysql table. Below is the python code that prints for an 'enum' mysql data type.

```
print '\t`%s` %s(\'%s\') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,' % (mysql_field_name, mysql_data_type, '\',\''.join(mysql_field_values.split(',')))
```

I need an enum field with % and $ as the values. I cannot seem to print the dollar sign in my output.

**This is what prints:**

```
`promotion_type` enum('','%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

**This is what I want it to print:**

```
`promotion_type` enum('$','%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

What do I have to change to make the dollar sign print?

Comment: `Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print '%s' % '$'
$
` is working for me, so what is your problem?

Comment: If I set `mysql_field_values = '$,%'` I get the result that you want.

Comment: @RC if you write an answer I will accept it. Turns out the dollar sign was my problem but you made me realize that the problem had nothing to do with python. I resolved my issue.

Comment: @user1645914, it's ok. Glad your issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_field_name = "promotion_type"
mysql_data_type = "enum"
mysql_field_values = "$,%"
print '\t`%s` %s(\'%s\') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,' % (mysql_field_name, mysql_data_type, '\',\''.join(mysql_field_values.split(',')))
```

`promotion_type` enum('$','%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

Check your variables to see if they are ok, because the print works without any problem.

My Python version:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
```

Comment: I double checked and realized the issue was indeed with my variables.